# How to access partition properties in java ee batch / jberet

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsr352, jberet

I have a job defined as below:

```
<step id="file-transfer">
    <chunk checkpoint-policy="item" item-count="10" retry-limit="10">
        <reader ref="allTrusteeCustomerFilesReader">
            <properties>
                <property name="part-page-first-offset" value="#{partitionPlan['part-page-first-offset']}"/>
                <property name="part-page-last-offset" value="#{partitionPlan['part-page-last-offset']}"/>
                <property name="part-page-length" value="#{partitionPlan['part-page-length']}"/>
                <property name="part-sort-field" value="#{partitionPlan['part-sort-field']}"/>
                <property name="part-sort-ascending" value="#{partitionPlan['part-sort-ascending']}"/>
            </properties>
        </reader>
        <processor ref="customerFileLocalToGoogleStorageProcessor"/>
        <writer ref="customerFileWriter">
            <properties>
                <property name="set-google-cloud-migrated" value="true"/>
            </properties>
        </writer>


        <skippable-exception-classes>
            <include class="be.valuya.gestemps.server.file.batch.error.NoLocalStorageDataException"/>
            <include class="be.valuya.gestemps.server.file.batch.error.TargetAlreadyPresentException"/>
            <include class="be.valuya.gestemps.server.file.batch.error.CustomerFileAlreadyMigratedException"/>
        </skippable-exception-classes>
        <retryable-exception-classes>
            <include class="be.valuya.gestemps.server.file.batch.error.TransferToGoogleFailedException"/>
        </retryable-exception-classes>
    </chunk>

    <partition>
        <mapper ref="customerFilePartitionMapper"/>
    </partition>

    <end on="COMPLETED"/>
</step>
```

The referenced mappers creates an Array of Properties, with defined values, and returns it:

```
    PartitionPlanImpl partitionPlan = new PartitionPlanImpl();
    partitionPlan.setPartitions(partitionCount);
    partitionPlan.setPartitionProperties(partitionProperties);

    return partitionPlan;
```

It is correctly called on step starts and returns properties with the correct keys defined.

However, Im not able to get the partition plan properties from my reader step. None of the job context properties nor the step context properties contains anything. I see no error in console. The job instance parameters only contains the parameters set at runtime. None of the parameters/properties names conflicts. Attempt to inject them using @BatchProperty leave the fields null.

The batch is started as follow:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    // Fill parameters...
    long executionId = jobOperator.start(jobName, properties);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you share a simplified test app through e.g., github? It will be easier for me to debug it.  Or you can also file a [JIRA issue](https://issues.redhat.com/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20JBERET%20ORDER%20BY%20key%20DESC) and attach a reproducer test app at

Comment: I created a minimal app to reproduce: https://github.com/cghislai/jberet-partitoin-test

Comment: ill be damn, setting primitive `int` in the partition plan properties was the issue :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partition plan was puting integers in the `Properties` map. It seems strings are expected:

```
//
Properties partProperties;
partProperties.setProperty("plan-property", "20"); // <--- Use setProperty to enforce String values rather than put
// ...

PartitionPlanImpl partitionPlan = new PartitionPlanImpl();
partitionPlan.setPartitions(partitionCount);
partitionPlan.setPartitionProperties(partitionProperties);

return partitionPlan;
```

Answer (score 0):

To see the partition properties in work, you will need to inject the item reader properties into your item reader class. For example,

```java
public class AllTrusteeCustomerFilesReader implements ItemReader {
  @Inject
  @BatchProperty(name = "part-page-first-offset")
  String partPageFirstOffset;

...
}
```

The above field `partPageFirstOffset` will hold the value of the item reader property `part-page-first-offset`, which is defined in job.xml to reference partition property `part-page-first-offset`.